# como funciona not for replication en los triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

hola estoy tratando de entender como funcionan los trigger cuando se especifica not for replication , si por ejemplo tengo un trigger

`instead of update not for replication`

que trabaja sobre una vista y en lugar de actualizar esa vista lo que hace es actualizar la tabla base pero no se para que sirve el

> not for replication

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes encontrar información al respecto aquí: [Controlar restricciones, identidades y desencadenadores con NOT FOR REPLICATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms152529.aspx).

Pero básicamente, solo es algo que aplica cuando estás replicando un servidor SQL Server a otro servidor. En ese caso, si el trigger llega a correr durante el proceso de replicación, eso a menudo no es el comportamiento deseado y puede corromper los datos en el servidor replicado.

Por esta razón, se puede agregar `NOT FOR REPLICATION` a la definición de un trigger para que este no se ejecute si la modificación de datos ocurre durante el proceso de replicación.